# Passing a FileDocumentReadConfiguration to a document struct's initializer in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

When you create a document-based SwiftUI project, the document struct contains the following initializer:

```
init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
    // Code to open an existing document
}
```

In the initial text editor project that Xcode supplies, you don't have to supply the configuration argument when calling the document's initializer in the App file.

```
var body: some Scene {
    DocumentGroup(newDocument: Document()) { file in
        ContentView(document: file.$document)
    }
}
```

In my project the document contains an array of another struct and saves the document in a file package. Now the compiler complains that I'm missing the `configuration` argument in the call to the document's initializer.

If I supply a `FileDocumentReadConfiguration` object as the `configuration` argument,

```
DocumentGroup(newDocument: Document(configuration: FileDocumentReadConfiguration())) { file in
    ContentView(document: file.$document)
}
```

The compiler provides the following error message:

> FileDocumentReadConfiguration cannot be constructed because it has no
> accessible initializers

The information on `FileDocumentReadConfiguration` in Apple's documentation has nothing on initializers. Searching for `FileDocumentReadConfiguration` on Google yields only Apple's documentation and an unanswered question on the Hacking with Swift forums. No one has asked a question about this on Stack Overflow.

How do I supply a `FileDocumentReadConfiguration` object to the document's initializer or how can I avoid having to supply a `configuration` argument like the default project does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation details of the SwiftUI structs FileDocumentReadConfiguration, ReferenceFileDocumentConfiguration, etc. are not documented simply because they are not public. In order to be platform independent, SwiftUI takes care of a lot of default behaviours which can be confusing because by doing so it also hides a lot of information. In order to avoid the `ReadConfiguration` conundrum we need to do like the Xcode template and provide a custom initializer either with a default value there or in the variable declaration. That is the initialization that you call in the `DocumentGroup` init and let SwiftUI take care of the details.

Comment: Adding a custom initializer to the document struct eliminates the compiler error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var body: some Scene {
>     DocumentGroup(newDocument: Document()) { file in
>         ContentView(document: file.$document)
>     }
> }
> ```

This is a place where *a new* document is created, i.e. there is no file representation yet.

If you declare your `Document` as `FileDocument` you need to provide initializer with `ReadConfiguration`, which in this case is typealias to `FileDocumentReadConfiguration` and this initializer will be called by system when your application is asked to open *existed* document of corresponding document type:

```
struct Document: FileDocument {

    // here configuration is-a `FileDocumentReadConfiguration`
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        // read here your content from configuration using `configuration.file` 
    }

   // ... other code
}
```

Comment: The Xcode project for a SwiftUI document app provides this init for the document so I have the initializer. The problem is the compiler wants me to provide a ReadConfiguration instance when calling the initializer. The `required` keyword works only for classes. When I add `required` to the init for my struct, I get the following compiler error: required initializer in non-class type.